# Nginx rate limit annotation- not setting the limit correctly

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, rate-limiting

I am pretty new to kubernetes,nginx. I have a service deployed on GCP GKE, having nginx ingress.

As part of rate limiting, we have this configuration

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm: "10"

As per documentation,The burst limit is set to this limit multiplied by the burst multiplier, the default multiplier is 5.

ie 10*5=50 is the total request allowed as per the setting.

So in total we will have 50 requests having a pass and remaining fail with error 503. However, while testing we see around 75-80 request passing the rest failing, but ideally 50 requests to pass an remaining to fail. Why is this behaving indifferently? Is there any other configuration to be set?

Ideal behaviour -50 request to have pass status

Comment: 50 is the number of requests accepted from a each IP each minute, so are you sure that the  75-80 are within one minute ?

Comment: yes we had tested it multiple times and got between 70-80 requests as passed, we had tested with a size of 120 requests and it was completed within 45 secs